# Ubuntu 20.04 LEMP Stack PHP 7.4 PDO Connection error

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mariadb

System: Ubuntu 20.04 (1 SQL Server and 1 Webserver)

mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB

PHP 7.4.3

I'm currently facing a problem setting up my LEMP Webserver.

I already configured PHP and Nginx, also secure installed mariadb.
But no matter what I do I always run in the following problem:

```
mysql error log: 2021-08-22 15:47:40 37 [Warning] Access denied for user 
             ''@'Hostname' (using password: NO)
Webbrowser:   Server can't handle request HTTP500 Error
```

I created the database user called webcompiler@Server_ip on the database and gave him full permissions
on the specific database.

On the SQL Server itself I can login via mysql -u root -p (works fine).
But not via mysql -u webcompiler -p

my.cnf in mariadb:

```
[mysqld]
skip-networking=0
skip-bind-address
```

The PDO Connection script:

```
<?php

$servername ="*";
$dBUsername = "webcompiler";
$dBPassword = "*";
$dBName = "*";


$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dBName",$dBUsername , $dBPassword);

if ($pdo->connect_error) {     die("Connection failed: " . $pdo->connect_error); }
```

Thanks for the help so far!

I changed accordingly but now I get this error:

```
[Warning] Access denied for user 'webcompiler'@'host' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: This `if(!$pdo) {` makes no sense and needs to be removed

Comment: You are missing the closing quotes after `$dBName`.

Comment: And for the check you can use `if ($pdo->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $pdo->connect_error);
}`

Comment: Thanks for the Help! Now it seems to work, but I get  a new error: *[Warning] Access denied for user 'webcompiler'@'host' (using password: YES)* Wheres that comming from?

Comment: I checked the Log again but I only get Access denied for user 'webcompiler'@'host' (using password: YES)
Same as by trying to direct connect via mariadb -u

Answer (score 0):

As "Using Password Yes" points to a wrong password, I changed it to a
simple one to see if that fixes the Error.

It did. I changed it to another one and escaping special characters was the key to making it work.

Thanks for all the help!